# Bit operations resulting in an unsigned large number instead of a negative number

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

```
>>> result = 0
>>> x = -2
>>> 
>>> for i in range(32):
...     c = 1 << i
...     if c & x: result |= c
... 
>>> print(result)
4294967294
```

As you can see, the expected result should be `-2`, however the program prints `4294967294`, which is the two's complement representation of the negative number.

How to fix it? And is there `signed integer` in python?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3 ? I'm not sure it would be the same, as they use integers differently.

Comment: Both Python 2/3 give exact same result. I don't think the python versions matters in term of this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python (even Python 2) do not enforce integer subtypes. You could loop up to 48 (instead) of 32, and Python would automatically convert the number to a long, and you would get `281474976710654L`. It would be more explicit if you were printing `repr(result)` on Python 2.x because you would get `4294967294L` showing the conversion to long

**You** know that what you want is a signed 32 bits integer, but Python does not know it. All you can do is an explicit conversion :

```
if result > 0x7fffffff: result = int(result - 0x100000000)
```

(the `int` conversion forces conversion from long to int under Python 2.x)

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I see just 3 possibilities

1. result variable is more then 32 bit long

   - try range (64) ....
2. result variable is unsigned int instead of signed

   - do not code in python so I do not know how the variables are declared/defined
   - so handle this with that in mind
3. result variable is arbitrary size (big int)

   - in this case your approach will not work no matter what
   - need to handle sign separately ...
   - so range (bits-1)
   - and add something like:
   - `sx=x; if (x<0) x=-x;` ... before the loop
   - `if (sx<0) result=-result;` ... after the loop